# getSize() deprecated in API level 30

Tags: android, deprecation-warning, android-api-levels

I used the getSize() method to get the screen sizes:

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val fragmentActivity = requireActivity()
    ...
    val wm = fragmentActivity.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager 
    val display = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        fragmentActivity.display
    } else {
        wm.defaultDisplay 
    }
    val size = Point()
    display?.getSize(size)
    
    // get screen sizes
    val width = size.x
    val height = size.y
    ...
}
```

But with API level 30 the method getSize() is declared deprecated.

What can be used instead of getSize() for obtain screen sizes?

Thank you for any comment/answer!

**Solution**:

```
val wm = fragmentActivity.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
val width: Int
val height: Int
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
    val windowMetrics = wm.currentWindowMetrics
    val windowInsets: WindowInsets = windowMetrics.windowInsets

    val insets = windowInsets.getInsetsIgnoringVisibility(
          WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars() or WindowInsets.Type.displayCutout())
    val insetsWidth = insets.right + insets.left
    val insetsHeight = insets.top + insets.bottom

    val b = windowMetrics.bounds
    width = b.width() - insetsWidth
    height = b.height() - insetsHeight
} else {
    val size = Point()
    val display = wm.defaultDisplay // deprecated in API 30
    display?.getSize(size) // deprecated in API 30
    width = size.x
    height = size.y
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Use `WindowManager#getCurrentWindowMetrics()` to obtain an instance of
> WindowMetrics and use WindowMetrics#getBounds() instead."

It's from Android documentation.
[Android doc]
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display#getSize(android.graphics.Point)

Answer (score 9):

If like me, you just want to get the window size, here is a compat version :

```
fun WindowManager.currentWindowMetricsPointCompat(): Point {
    return if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        val windowInsets = currentWindowMetrics.windowInsets
        var insets: Insets = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars())
        windowInsets.displayCutout?.run {
            insets = Insets.max(insets, Insets.of(safeInsetLeft, safeInsetTop, safeInsetRight, safeInsetBottom))
        }
        val insetsWidth = insets.right + insets.left
        val insetsHeight = insets.top + insets.bottom
        Point(currentWindowMetrics.bounds.width() - insetsWidth, currentWindowMetrics.bounds.height() - insetsHeight)
    }else{
        Point().apply {
            defaultDisplay.getSize(this)
        }
    }
}
```

it will take care of removing insets of navigation bars and display cutout areas to get the same result in both case

Answer (score 8):

The new [Jetpack WindowManager library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/window) provides a common API surface for new Window Manager features (e.g. foldable devices and Chrome OS) throughout old and new platform versions.

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta02"
}
```

Jetpack WindowManager offers two ways to retrieve [WindowMetrics](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/window/layout/WindowMetrics) information, as an asynchronous stream or synchronously.

**Asynchronous WindowMetrics flow:**

Use [`WindowInfoRepository#currentWindowMetrics`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/window/layout/WindowInfoRepository#currentWindowMetrics()) to get notified by the library when there’s a window size change, independent of whether this change fires a configuration change.

```
import androidx.window.layout.WindowInfoRepository
import androidx.window.layout.WindowInfoRepository.Companion.windowInfoRepository
import androidx.window.layout.WindowMetrics
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import androidx.lifecycle.flowWithLifecycle

lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    windowInfoRepository().currentWindowMetrics.flowWithLifecycle(lifecycle)
        .collect { windowMetrics: WindowMetrics ->
           val currentBounds = windowMetrics.bounds // E.g. [0 0 1350 1800]
           val width = currentBounds.width()
           val height = currentBounds.height()
        }
}
```

- Note: `lifecycleScope` and `flowWithLifecycle()` are part of [Jetpack Lifecycle library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle).

**Synchronous WindowMetrics:**

Use [WindowMetricsCalculator](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/window/layout/WindowMetricsCalculator) when writing code in a view where the asynchronous API can be too hard to deal with (such as `onMeasure` or during testing).

```
import androidx.window.layout.WindowMetricsCalculator
import androidx.window.layout.WindowMetrics

val windowMetrics = WindowMetricsCalculator.getOrCreate().computeCurrentWindowMetrics(activity)
val currentBounds = windowMetrics.bounds // E.g. [0 0 1350 1800]
val width = currentBounds.width()
val height = currentBounds.height()
```

Ref: [Unbundling the WindowManager | Android Developers Medium](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/unbundling-the-windowmanager-fa060adb3ce9)

Comment: import androidx.window.WindowManager doesn't seem to exist

Comment: `WindowManager` was removed in [v1.0.0-alpha10](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/window#1.0.0-alpha10) in favour of `WindowInfoRepository` or `WindowMetricsCalculator`. I've just updated the answer. Thanks.